# How to show convergence of integration when domain is moving.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $Q\subset \mathbb R^2$ be a cube centered at $(0,0)$, with side length $2$. Let $I$ denote the segment from $(-0.5,0)$ to $(0.5,0)$.

Define $$\tau(x):=\operatorname{dist}(x,I)$$ for $x\in Q$.

Given function $u\in C_c^\infty(Q)$.

I am considering the following integration:
$$
\int_{I}u(x)\,d\mathcal H^{1}\text{ and }\int_{\{x:\,\tau(x)=\epsilon\}}u(x)\,d\mathcal H^{1}
$$

It looks to me that the following relation hold:
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\{x:\,\tau(x)=\epsilon\}}u(x)\,d\mathcal H^{1} = 2\int_{I}u(x)\,d\mathcal H^{1}
$$
but I am having trouble with dealing the moving domain... How can I prove this convergence?

---

The general case I need to show in the end is $Q\in\mathbb R^N$ and $I$ to be $N-1$ rectifiable set with $\mathcal H^{N-1}(I)<\infty$, and prove the same result.

Any help is really welcome!

Comment: What are your differentials $d\mathcal{H}^{N-1}$?

Comment: @charlestoncrabb sorry it is the 1-d Hausdorff measure. Corrected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\{ x : \tau(x)=\epsilon \}$ consists of the segment from $(-0.5,\epsilon)$ to $(0.5,\epsilon)$, the segment from $(-0.5,-\epsilon)$ to $(0.5,-\epsilon)$, and two semicircles joining these segments. (It is a good idea to draw a picture of this.) Argue that:

1. The integrals on the semicircles go to zero.
2. For each $x \in [-0.5,0.5]$, $u((x,\pm \epsilon))$ goes to $u((x,0))$ uniformly in $x$ as $\epsilon$ goes to zero.

Comment: Show $1$ is quick, and in $2$ uniform convergence is not hard too. But how uniformly convergence help to proof? What kind of convergence tools should I use? Since the domain is changing... I don't think LDCT will work...

Comment: Moreover, I actually need $I$ to be $N-1$ rectifiable and do this in $\mathbb R^N$. Do you think your argument can be generalized to this case?

Comment: @tankonetoone (@ first question) On the segments, you can change variables so that the integrand changes rather than the domain. Then you can use pretty much any convergence theorem you like (uniform convergence is strong!)

Comment: @tankonetoone (@ second question) In $\mathbb{R}^N$ I think the situation is analogous: you have two $(N-1)$-dimensional hyperplanes and two half-spheres.

Comment: I see your point. Let me try to work out the details!

Comment: What I worried is when I have a curve instead of a straight line, the change variables may not work since the curve can have different directions...

Comment: @tankonetoone I think in the case when $I$ is a curve, provided it is sufficiently smooth you should be able to locally straighten it (using methods which are pretty standard in Sobolev space theory; in particular, they are in Evans) and then proceed the same way.

Comment: I think if $I$ is $C^1$ would be enough right?

Comment: @tankonetoone I think even just Lipschitz is enough, but the details are more tedious if you don't have $C^1$.